# No puedo instalar sql server, por un servicio dañado de windows

Tags: sql-server, windows10

es que tenía instalado sql server 2014 pero tenia problemas con el arranque de un servicio de sql server, entonces lo desinstale y borre una carpeta en archivos de programa, que decía sql server, creo que ahí iba un servicio de windows o de sql server que dice error en ejecutar servicio, el servicio es sql server VSS Writer, y debido a eso no puedo volver a instalar sql server 2014, que puedo hacer, es problema de windows o sql server, y si tiene alguna solución[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Formatear la pc o volver a instalar SQL?

Comment: Ese servicio, si buscaras 30 segundos, verías que está relacionado con la instalación de SQL Server y borraste todo a medias.